# Trying to understand promises behaviour in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to write a script which checks an invalid JSON string and then throws an error, which I in turn can log in the console. I'm using promises for this (in order to better understand how they work).

```
function parsePromised(value) {
  var promise = new Promise(
    function(fulfilled, rejected) {
      try {
        JSON.parse(value)
      } catch (e) {
        rejected(e)
      }
      fulfilled('fulfilled')
    }
  )
  console.log(promise)
  return promise;
}

parsePromised('{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": {"4": 4, "5": {"6": 6}}}').then(console.log);
```

For a reason I don't understand, console returns me three lines (two for console.log in my script and one with an error). Here it is:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: "fulfilled"}

Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

What I'm trying to understand is why the output in the first case differs from the output in the second and why the error is thrown. I think I invoke promise just fine. Thanks!

Comment: The final error i believe is because `console.log` needs its `this` or context set to console. When it is called it isn't set to the console. You should do `.then(console.log.bind(console));` One of its many quirks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Illegal invocation` actually has nothing to do with the promise. In the browser, `.log()` must be bound to `console` when being passed around, so you want something like this:

```
parsePromised('{"1": 1, "2": 2, "3": {"4": 4, "5": {"6": 6}}}')
  .then(console.log.bind(console));
```

As for the other problem, I can't reproduce, I can only see one extra line. See https://jsfiddle.net/sbonrcxm/

Comment: Strange, because Chrome definitely logs this second line when I paste the script directly into the console.

I've also tried to pass a wrong JSON string and the console log says that it wasnt caught in the promise, but still the output of the promise gives me catch value just fine.

    Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]:

    Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. The first line is the console showing you the last statement evaluated, the second being the `console.log()` and the third is the `console.log` in `.then()`.